# How to set javascript files to cache in htaccess on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, cache

For ExpiresByType in .htaccess, what is the difference between 'application/javascript', 'application/x-javascript', and all the other types I run into online?

Every thing I find on how to do this suggests adding 3-4 lines like:

```
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/js
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 week"
```

But do I really need all 3? Can I just use one that will work on my server and for all my users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the difference between `application/javascript`, `application/x-javascript`

That is the mime-type that your server is responding with (in the `Content-Type` HTTP response header).

> But do I really need all 3?

No. You only need to specify the mime-type that your server is responding with - check the `Content-Type` header.

When you see examples with *multiple* entries (as in your example), it's either a case of blind copy/paste, or it's intended to be a "catch-all" solution for all servers - but it's unnecessary and just bloats the code, harder to debug etc. However, if these have different cache values then it's just plain wrong.

Your server is probably responding with `application/javascript`.

Comment: It is responding with `application/javascript`. Thanks.